# How to terminate C# based Excel Application instance?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working on a small code to read some Excel files. I've linked the COM library for Excel 15, and am using the following code to read Excel files:

```
excelInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook workbook = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(@excelOpenFileDialog.FileName);
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
Range UsedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
int lastUsedRow = UsedRange.Row + UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
```

The problem is I don't know how to terminate the Excel instance once my processing is finished. The Excel Application Interface isn't Disposable, so is there another way ?

Comment: There's a method for closing the instance: `excelInstance.Quit()`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, you should make that an answer, maybe also include a MS reference.

Answer (score 4):

Disposing the Excel COM objects can be a bit finicky. Make sure you're calling `Close` on your Workbook when finished, and `Quit` on your instance of Excel.Application.

Release the objects by calling `FinalReleaseComObject()`, and for redundancy, explicitly null the COM objects:

```
Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheet);
Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);


sheet = null;
workbook = null;
app = null;
```

Lastly, if the buggers still don't seem to go away after calling the appropriate disposal methods, explicitly releasing them, and nulling the references to the objects , call the Garbage Collector:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And hopefully that will finally do it.

Cheers.

Edit: Also, be sure to do this in an exception handler if there's a chance your code will bomb while you're using the Interop objects, or because of them. You'll leave zombie processes even if the parent terminates.

Comment: When doing workbook.Close you might want to pop a False afterwards, which will tell Excel to close the workbook and ignore any changes.  Otherwise you run the risk of getting a dialog box appearing that may not be visible (if the app is not visible).

Comment: Tried everything you suggested, and even then EXCEL.EXE doesn't go away from Task Manager .. :/

Comment: Hmmm. Make sure, like steveo was saying, that you save your Workbooks appropriately, or ignore problems when closing, otherwise you might leave a hanging invisible dialog box. If you want, you could update your question and show us some more code.

Comment: @steveo40, where do I mention that False ? I didn't fully understand your placement of the False message/value.

Comment: I think what steveo is trying to say, is pass 'false' as the first argument of the Close method of the Workbook object in case some unintentional changes were made prior to attempting to close it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.close%28v=office.14%29.aspx You must have some errors, open dialogs, or unresolved issues if the above solution isn't removing your interop objects.

Answer (score 0):

As per the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit%28v=office.11%29.aspx), use the `Quit()` method to close your instance, as such:

```
var excelInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

// Do stuff

excelInstance.Quit();
```