# How to kill instance of Word/Excel File in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, ms-word

I have two files demo1.docx,demo2.docx.When I will open these two files then it created two instances into Task Manager in Application Section and created one process WinWord.exe into process Section.When I  kill demo1.docx instance it automatically kill another instance but I want to kill only that instance demo1.docx. Currently I am using this code for kill the instance

```
string instanceName="demo1.docx";

Process[] runingProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < runingProcess.Length; i++)
    if (runingProcess[i].MainWindowTitle.Contains(instanceName))
        runingProcess[i].Kill();
```

Comment: [Stopping Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05abh773%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672427/how-to-terminate-c-sharp-based-excel-application-instance

Answer (score 4):

We have to close them, not kill them. To take control of instance already running, you can use this code:

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("winword").Count() > 0)
{
    Word.Application wordInstance = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

    foreach (Word.Document doc in wordInstance.Documents)
    {
        if (doc.Name == "demo1.docx")
        {
            doc.Close();
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all documents are opened in the same process, killing it will automatically close all of them. Maybe you can use Word Automation to close a specific document.

Here there is a working solution : 
[how to close a running instance of Word document? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445831/how-to-close-a-running-instance-of-word-document-c)